# Error while retrieving resultset

Tags: java, sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to retrieve a resultset from a procedure in Java but I'm unable to do so. Although usually I easily retrieve resultset this time a null pointer exception is encountered.

Here is my sql server 2008 proceedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SSSMLTransaction]
@acid int,@subacid int
AS
BEGIN
CREATE  TABLE trans ( Vtype varchar(10),Vno varchar(5),Vdate date,Narr varchar(50),dr numeric(13,2),cr numeric(13,2),DCIND varchar(1)); 
 insert into trans(Vtype,Vno,Vdate,Narr,dr,cr,DCIND) 
 (select 'Cash',cd.V_no,cv.VDate,cv.Narr1,cd.Debit,cd.Credit,cd.DCIND from CVDetail cd join CashVoucher cv on cd.V_no=cv.Vno where
cd.ANO=@acid and cd.Party_Code=@subacid) ;
   select * from trans;
   drop table trans;
END
```

And here is my Java function:

```
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{call SSSMLTransaction(?,?)}");
    cs.setInt(1, acid);
    cs.setInt(2, prtyid);
    cs.execute();
    rs=cs.getResultSet();
```

But I got a empty resultset.

Comment: What does cs.execute() return? True or false?

Comment: I don't know what effect dropping the table will have before you've read your ResultSet, looks suspect to me.

Comment: cs.execute returns false @gimby

Comment: even if i remove that particular line still gives the same error @NickJ

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 ResultSet rs = cs.executeQuery();
```

Comment: by doing this it gives me error:  The statement did not return a result set

Comment: I didn't understand your error. Why it doesn't give ResultSet?

Comment: dat's what m lookoing for :(

Answer (score 0):

Best way to retrieve a data from Procedure is as follows :

```
public static void executeProcedure(Connection con) {
   try {
          CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall(...);
      .....  //Set call parameters, if you have IN,OUT, or IN/OUT parameters

      boolean results = stmt.execute();
      int rsCount = 0;

      //Loop through the available result sets.
     while (results) {
           ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();
           //Retrieve data from the result set.
           while (rs.next()) {
        ....// using rs.getxxx() method to retieve data
           }
           rs.close();

        //Check for next result set
        results = stmt.getMoreResults();
      } 
      stmt.close();
   }
   catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

In your case , i suppose there is no data to return based on your SQL query.